# Laravel cookies with redirect

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, nginx, laravel-forge

I've got Laravel cookies working on my localhost but not on Laravel Forge. On Forge, I get a Nginx `502` bad gateway error that I can't analyze because Forge doesn't give access to error logs. Might someone help?

Here's my code:

```
 \Cookie::queue('linkedin_user', $li_user); //commenting out this line allows for the proper redirect on Forge
 return redirect('/signup');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get cookies to work so I ended up using `Session` instead. An easy swap with no hassles.

```
\Session::put('linkedin_user', $li_user);
return redirect('/signup');
```